# How show spinner only textbox active Angular 4

Tags: angular

How to show the spinning wheel only in the active textbox?

I use angular 5, that is my code I have N textboxes

```html
<div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #fff !important" *ngIf="searching "><span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span></div>
```

[image: show Picture]

Comment: Please share more code or just a https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need for each input with spinner make its own variable. The easiest way, for each input make own component with context field `boolean` 'searching' who will be responsible for his spinner.
If this is not your way, you can take from each input focus status by methods (blur) (focus) in html, but I think this is wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

To track which form control is “searching” you could have an array of objects, each containing your FormControl and some booleans to track the  state of your search

```
export interface SearchControl {
    control: FormControl;
    searching: Boolean;
}
```

And to display the spinner either create a component to wrap up this control, and have an ngIf on the spinner, or use ngClass and display the spinner using CSS.